# I can not see the CAPTCHA box

Tags: support, captcha

In posting an answer to a question, I get the following:

[image]

But I can not see the CAPTCHA box in the page. What should I do?

Comment: To avoid the pop-up box in the first place, it sometimes helps to avoid some specific triggers for the captcha. Based on some experimentation, I think fast answers are a trigger. So even if one has already written the whole answer elsewhere and just needs to copy paste it, wait 30 seconds or so before submitting the answer. Code only answers seem another trigger. Adding some more text can help to avoid the pop-up.

Comment: Are you in China and/or use browser addons or others settings for tracking protection or disable scripts?

Comment: Yes, I am in China. I found another workaround: I opened the link of the question in mobile phone, and the unposted answer was synchronized there. Then I successfully posted the answer in mobile phone.

Comment: Please see this post on the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257868/please-revisit-the-captcha-china-issue and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153561/human-verification-page-not-loading-in-china

Comment: Thank you very much!